# UnityプロジェクトでYouTubeの動画を再生したい

Tags: unity2d, nuget

Unityプロジェクトで、iOS・Android向けにYouTubeの動画を再生できるアプリを作成したいと考えています。
UnityプロジェクトにNuGetパッケージ「videolibrary.3.0.0」を組み込んだのですが、

```
var youTube = YouTube.Default;
var video = await youTube.GetVideoAsync(uri);
```

の部分で

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'VideoLibrary.YouTube+<ParseVideos>
```

といった例外をスローします。こちらの原因は分かりますでしょうか。

渡しているURL形式は `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=` と `https://youtu.be/` で試しましたが結果は同じでした。

**環境**
Unity 2018.3.13f1
videolibrary.3.0.0

Comment: この記事がそのもののようですので参考に。[UnityでYoutubeの動画を再生する](https://tofgame.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/31/234948)

Comment: その記事を参考に対応したのですが、例外がスローされてしまいます。NuGetパッケージ自体初めて扱うのですが、Unityへの設定で記事以外に対応しなければならない箇所などありますでしょうか。

Comment: 紹介記事のリンクで[UnityでNuGetパッケージを使う方法](https://qiita.com/jhorikawa_err/items/f75539ffe6cd7a360f65)がありますが、その中に「あとは、解凍された中にあるlibフォルダの中のバージョンのあった各種dllをUnityのPluginsフォルダに入れればこれで使えます（あくまでMonoに対応しているdllのみ）」とあります。2017/12時点の情報ですが、まだ変わらないのかもしれません。ちなみにUnityの経験は無いので、.NET 4.8 WinFormsアプリで[GitHub VideoLibrary Readmeのサンプルソース部分](https://github.com/omansak/libvideo)を組み込んだら正常に動作してダウンロード出来ました。iOS/AndroidではなくMono(Mac/Linux)対象のプロジェクトを作成してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: この記事は2020/1に更新されてますが、まだUnityC#はMonoのみのようです。[Unity であらゆる C#(.NET) パッケージを使う（例：opencv）](https://www.fast-system.jp/unity-nugetforunity/)